# how an image is hidden in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
<div id="c2"><img  ng-hide="myValue" ng-src="D:/AngularJS/images/Assets/WIP.png" /></div>
  <div id="c3"  ng-hide="myValue1"  class="ng-hide"><img  ng-hide="myValue1"  ng-src="D:/AngularJS/images/Assets/compleated.png" /></div>
```

// create angular controller

```
validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

        // function to submit the form after all validation has occurred    

        $scope.myvalue=true;
        $scope.submitForm = function() {

        // check to make sure the form is completely valid

    };
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: Please try being more clear when asking and use a proper style as  suggested  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
  <div id="c2"><img  ng-hide="myvalue" ng-src="D:/AngularJS/images/Assets/WIP.png" /></div>
  <div id="c3"  ng-hide="myValue1"  class="ng-hide"><img  ng-hide="myValue1"  ng-src="D:/AngularJS/images/Assets/compleated.png" /></div>
```

scope is case-sensitive, change myValue to myvalue

Check codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGdgby

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code.

```
<img ng-cloak  ng-if="message.Attachment" ng-src="path here" alt="  {{message.Attachment}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I will omit unnecessary details

```
<img ng-hide="cond" ng-click="cond = !cond" ... />
```

Also, you can use not only click event. You can use an any condition you want. Just try change `cond` variable in some other place and check what happen.